# What is the base value of various 'Fortify' potions and enchantments?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am playing *Skyrim SE* with most graphical/texture/ENB mods (on Linux) and [Vokrii](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/26176) for talents.

I would like to reinforce my *enchanting* by crafting potions of Fortify Enchanting and now I managed to get +60% combined *Fortify Alchemy* gear (15% a piece).

When I try to craft such potion, it goes from *4%* without gear, to *7%*.
Is the base value of this potion 4%?

Where can I find such base values?
I guess I could use the *Fortify Enchanting* --> *Fortify Alchemy* loop for some tries, but how much can I leverage it? Is there an overall cap?

I understand that with *Vokrii* talents I could level up to 100 Alchemy and get 100% boost (hence I would imagine the base to go 4% --> 8%).

Again, trying to run *glitch-less*.

Thanks!